# Why does searching for text of a pound sign using Python's BeautifulSoup return no results when the page contains that symbol?

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/'

result = requests.get(url)

doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text,"html.parser")

prices = doc.find(text = "£")

print(prices)
```

Output:

```
None
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

With searching by text you will only find exact matches and there is no single element that only contains `£`.

#### How to fix?

Use regex to find a single element that contains `£`:

```
prices = doc.find(text=re.compile("£"))
```

or multiple elements:

```
prices = doc.find_all(text=re.compile("£"))
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/'
result = requests.get(url)

doc = BeautifulSoup(result.content)
prices = doc.find_all(text=re.compile("£"))

print(prices)
```

#### Output

```
['£51.77', '£53.74', '£50.10', '£47.82', '£54.23', '£22.65', '£33.34', '£17.93', '£22.60', '£52.15', '£13.99', '£20.66', '£17.46', '£52.29', '£35.02', '£57.25', '£23.88', '£37.59', '£51.33', '£45.17']
```